# How to change maven build directory?

Tags: java, maven, compilation

I have a maven project which I compile with Netbeans. I there a way to specify a different build directory where the compiled binary code is copied after compilation?

Comment: best answer I found: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12598554/520567

Comment: Agreed, using POM profiles is definitely the most flexible and powerful solution IMO.

Answer (score 24):

Sure. Update your POM with:

```
<build>
  <directory>my_new_build_path</directory>
</build>
```

Part 2: To specify the output path for a WAR:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <warName>test-web-app</warName>
        <outputDirectory>my_output_path</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Is this going to work for every sub maven project if I place it only on my parent POM file?

Comment: Good point. Having this setting means that the build directory for every module is the same, instead of one directory per module.

Comment: I forgot to write that I have bundles without `maven-war-plugin`. I also have `maven-compiler-plugin`. How I can configure it to change the output directory?

Comment: You can modify the outputDirectory build setting. If you just want to change the output path of the JAR file, then you can use maven-jar-plugin.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why not reconfigure netbeans to use the standard maven structure.  With eclipse, i execute the following on the command line for a web project with a pom.xml.  It generates all the necessary eclipse project files for me:  mvn -Dwtpversion=2.0 eclipse:eclipse     I'd be surprised if there isn't a similar plugin for netbeans.

Answer (score 19):

```xml
<project>
  <build>
    <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I tested it - the compiled files are moved there. I want to specify the build directory for the final WAR package.

Comment: OK, all you need is [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html). I don't feel what exactly you need to set (I though it's compiled stuff directory) so choose what you need.