# location of pom.xml file

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm using maven 3.2.5 and need to configure the default build path of maven.

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587375/how-to-change-maven-build-directory) I found that the changes need to be made in `pom.xml` file.

I just can't find the pom.xml file. Can anyone please tell me the default location of `pom.xml` file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default pom.xml is at root path of the project, else the path is overridden via -f flag.

Comment: to have a `pom.xml` do we need to have a maven project created first. Donot we have a `pom.xml` file right after maven is installed.

Comment: Nope pom.xml has to be created along with the project structure. If you are using Maven archetype then that's a different story altogether.

Answer (score 4):

Also, be sure to have your project converted to a Maven Project:

[image]

Without this, there'll be no `pom.xml` file available at root path of the  project.

For more info: [What is POM ?](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)