# Out-of-tree build with maven. Is it possible?

Tags: java, maven, build

I start learning packaging for several distros (currently Cygwin and Debian).

They have requirement to build system to allow **out-of-tree build** (synonym **out-of-source build**):

http://wiki.debian.org/UpstreamGuide#Out-of-Tree_Builds

To work-around "dumb" build system for example **cygport** recommend use **lndir** (from **xutils** project):

```
  lndir ${S} ${B}
  cd {B}
  ...build-commands...
```

I read **mvn(1)** man page but doesn't found anything appropriated. Next I just try:

```
  $ mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
  ...
  $ pwd
  /maven/simple
  $ ls 
  my-app
  $ mvn -f my-app/pom.xml compile
  ...
  [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) @ my-app ---
  [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /maven/simple/my-app/target/classes
```

As you can see **target** directory created in source root hierarchy while I look for a way to avoid this.

Is it possible **out-of-tree** build with maven? And how?

Comment: Please describe what you would expect. It's not clear.

Comment: **out-of-build** have strict meaning: you can cd to any directory and build project from it and all build artifact come exclusively to this directory. Setting target directory may satisfy this requiment. I look dipper if it work well.

Comment: Please describe why you put vote to close question? It satisfy SO guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be as simple as having a

```
<build>
    <directory>/your/build/directory</directory>
</build>
```

in your pom.xml. `/your/build/directory` need not be in the source tree and can be parameterized using the usual `${...}` syntax.

Cheers,

Comment: So there no any standard for build dir naming, so I must describe **-Dbuild.dir** key in project **INSTALL** file?

Comment: Also if I build from **any** directory I need **fix** build+directory value to workaround relative paths...

Comment: I think that this technique can be applied to Ant build system too... I just wander how it complicate to support project with subprojects...

Answer (score 8):

You could do like this to get it in your current working directory:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>Q13173063</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <buildDir>${user.dir}</buildDir>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <directory>${buildDir}</directory>
    </build>
</project>
```

Then you can issue

```
mvn -f my-app/pom.xml compile
```

And it will give you your classes in the current working directory.

And easily change to another output directory:

```
mvn -f my-app/pom.xml -DbuildDir=/tmp/build compile
```

Comment: Be careful using `${user.dir}` like this as `clean` will wipe the whole dir, not just a `target` subdir I think.