# bad path element "": no such file or directory in maven compile

Tags: java, maven, build, build-automation, pom.xml

I make as here:
[see highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908013/maven-how-to-change-path-to-target-directory-from-command-line)

added to my pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>otherOutputDir</id>
        <build>
            <directory>yourDirectory</directory>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

in cmd:

```
C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI>mvn compile -PotherOutputDir
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building hhsystem ui 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ ui ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ ui ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1251, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 11 source files to C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\yourDirectory\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] bad path element "": no such file or directory
C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyContextListener.java:[8,29]
 cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
location: package com.epam.hhsystem.util
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyContextListener.jav
a:[12,1] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.MyContextListener
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyApplicationListener
.java:[8,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
location: package com.epam.hhsystem.util
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyApplicationListener
.java:[14,1] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.MyApplicationListener
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\ApplicationWebListene
r.java:[9,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
location: package com.epam.hhsystem.util
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\ApplicationWebListene
r.java:[14,1] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.ApplicationWebListener
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[12,23] package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[24,16] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Logger
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CustomAuthentificationProvider
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\AbstractController.ja
va:[49,20] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getAllSkills()
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.services.UtilService
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[24,32] cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Logger
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CustomAuthentificationProvider
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[59,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[63,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[64,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[65,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[66,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\VacancyMenuController
.java:[79,20] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getAllSkills()
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.services.UtilService
[INFO] 16 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.463s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Oct 23 15:27:20 MSK 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/162M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project ui:
 Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] bad path element "": no such file or directory
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyContextListener.jav
a:[8,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
[ERROR] location: package com.epam.hhsystem.util
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyContextListener.jav
a:[12,1] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.MyContextListener
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyApplicationListener
.java:[8,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
[ERROR] location: package com.epam.hhsystem.util
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyApplicationListener
.java:[14,1] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.MyApplicationListener
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\ApplicationWebListene
r.java:[9,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
[ERROR] location: package com.epam.hhsystem.util
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\ApplicationWebListene
r.java:[14,1] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.ApplicationWebListener
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[12,23] package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[24,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class Logger
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CustomAuthentificationProvider
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\AbstractController.ja
va:[49,20] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : method getAllSkills()
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.services.UtilService
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[24,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : variable Logger
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CustomAuthentificationProvider
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[59,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[63,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[64,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[65,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[66,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\VacancyMenuController
.java:[79,20] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : method getAllSkills()
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.services.UtilService
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI>
```

What the reason of this problem?

**UPDATE**

ChristophT,

```
C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI>mvn -P otherOutputDir compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building hhsystem ui 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ ui ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ ui ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1251, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 11 source files to C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\yourDirectory\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] bad path element "": no such file or directory
C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyContextListener.java:[8,29]
 cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
location: package com.epam.hhsystem.util
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyContextListener.jav
a:[12,1] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.MyContextListener
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyApplicationListener
.java:[8,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
location: package com.epam.hhsystem.util
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyApplicationListener
.java:[14,1] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.MyApplicationListener
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\ApplicationWebListene
r.java:[9,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
location: package com.epam.hhsystem.util
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\ApplicationWebListene
r.java:[14,1] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.ApplicationWebListener
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[12,23] package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[24,16] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Logger
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CustomAuthentificationProvider
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\AbstractController.ja
va:[49,20] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getAllSkills()
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.services.UtilService
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[24,32] cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Logger
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CustomAuthentificationProvider
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[59,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[63,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[64,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[65,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[66,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\VacancyMenuController
.java:[79,20] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getAllSkills()
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.services.UtilService
[INFO] 16 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.632s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Oct 23 16:19:42 MSK 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/257M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project ui:
 Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] bad path element "": no such file or directory
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyContextListener.jav
a:[8,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
[ERROR] location: package com.epam.hhsystem.util
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyContextListener.jav
a:[12,1] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.MyContextListener
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyApplicationListener
.java:[8,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
[ERROR] location: package com.epam.hhsystem.util
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyApplicationListener
.java:[14,1] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.MyApplicationListener
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\ApplicationWebListene
r.java:[9,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
[ERROR] location: package com.epam.hhsystem.util
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\ApplicationWebListene
r.java:[14,1] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.ApplicationWebListener
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[12,23] package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[24,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class Logger
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CustomAuthentificationProvider
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\AbstractController.ja
va:[49,20] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : method getAllSkills()
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.services.UtilService
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[24,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : variable Logger
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CustomAuthentificationProvider
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[59,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[63,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[64,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[65,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[66,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\VacancyMenuController
.java:[79,20] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : method getAllSkills()
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.services.UtilService
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI>
```

Comment: sorry, my english is bad. What right variant?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't meant to say that way. Edited your question.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but does using the standard target directory work? i.e. does `mvn compile` work?

Comment: maybe you are right. How can I check it?

Answer (score 0):

The mvn command takes options before the goals. Plus a space is missing between `-P` and `otherOutputDir`. So following command should work:

```
mvn -P otherOutputDir compile
```

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your pom, i.e. the build and profiles sections