# target classes getting modified after import maven project

Tags: github, maven-3

git status shows 
modified:   target/classes/com/abcplusd/util/JSONUtil$1.class
after clone and import maven project from github repository.

part of Pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/*</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.springframework.build</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-maven</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your `target` folder is located under the folder containing your `.git` repository.  Hence, it appears that Git is viewing changed files from the build process as being something which should be versioned (they should *not*).

The general solution to this is to change your build target folder to something *outside* the path which Git manages.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can move target folder outside the path?

Comment: Have a look here for how to change your Maven target path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908013/maven-how-to-change-path-to-target-directory-from-command-line